# Download file (pdf) directly

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using drupal 7.14. I want to allow users to upload a file then create a link (using, atm, CKEditor) to it that will go straight to the file -- clicking on the link leads to a download, rather than the node associated with the uploaded file. I've created a File content type, and users can upload a file then link to it from another page.  To get this far I installed the modules CKEditor and CKEditor Link. However, clicking on the link to the "file" leads to a node containing a (direct) link, which is the step I want to get rid of.

To enable direct links I installed File Entity and CKEditor Link for Files. Unfortunately, File Entity seems to be not done yet and v7.x-2.0-unstable7 causes errors on my site -- after enabling it I can't upload any file.

What are the other ways of achieving this (seemingly straightforward) task? I don't mind switching to another editor if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I use [file_entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) 7.x-2.x-dev and have no problems. Maybe try this version. Is there any [Drupal.org issue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/file_entity) for the file_entity module that represents your broken functionality?

Beside that, the functionality you describe needs a **reference** not a link inside an editor. If you create a link to the file the only way to get the node that contains the file is to use something like Rules module to redirect file path to the node of that file.

So in order to create a link to the node of a field you can use the [field_reference](https://drupal.org/project/field_reference) module but you have to do it on a field outside the WYSIWYG editor.